# XCUITest - Click On Elements On HomeScreen

Tags: xcuitest

Is there a way in a XCUITest to access elements on the HomeScreen?

Right now if I background the running app, then try to access an element on it. 
i.e.

```
XCUIApplication().launch()
XCUIDevice.shared.press(XCUIDevice.Button.home)
XCUIApplication().otherElements["Dock"].icons["Settings"].tap()
```

`Failed to get matching snapshot: Application is not running`

I tried with coordinates also and got the same result since coordinates also seem to require an element from the main app, not the HomeScreen. It would be fine if I could click on elements on the HomeScreen as well.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can interact with other apps with XCTest.

Use `XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier:_)` initialisation to set up interacting with other apps.

In your case, you can open Settings app with

```swift
let springboard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")
springboard.icons("Settings").tap()
```

or skip springboard entirely and go directly to settings with

```swift
let settings = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.Preferences")
settings.launch()
```

You can find other bundle identifiers of the system apps here: https://github.com/rzakhar/XCTApps/blob/master/Sources/XCTApps/iOS.swift